# Integral Based on Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality, definite-integrals

Prove that there is a Constant $C$, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $1999$,then

$|p(0)| \le C \int_{-1}^{1} |p(x)|dx$

My approach to this question would be using the inequality

$\int_{0}^{A} \frac{\varnothing ^{p} (u)}{u^{1+p\alpha}}du$ $\le C_{\alpha,p}\int_{0}^{A} \frac{\varnothing (u)}{u^{1+\alpha}}du$ ---$(1)$

Where I would suppose on a random function $I(x)$ Which on Integrating gives us

$\lim_{x\to 0} \int I(x) = p(0)$ and thus would compare it with the $(1)$Inequality. But it is not helping out. With what approach should I further continue using the $(1)$ inequality only? Thank you:)

Comment: What is $\emptyset^p$?

Comment: @Hermi It is a function which is positive, measurable and sub additive on $(0,A)$

Comment: Can you show it for degree 1, 2, and 3? If so, how can we extend it to finite degree?

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry, but what working do I have to show can you please explain more about your question :)